# How can I copy the contents of multiple folders using the CMD copy command?

Tags: windows, copy, cmd, dos

I'm trying to copy the contents of multiple folders within the same directory into one new file. All the files I want to copy have the extension `.sql`.

When I try this - with one directory - it works:

```
directory>copy *.sql copy.sql
```

but when I try

```
directory>copy */*.sql copy.sql
```

I get

`The syntax of the command is incorrect.`

What am I doing wrong? I think I'm following the directions on [this site](http://ss64.com/nt/copy.html) correctly, but am I?

I'm not sure if this makes a difference, but I'm using Windows 7.

TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this would work. Standard Windows command shells won't do wildcard matching on path components, just the final part of the path argument. As well, you've got a forward slash in there, which is used for command arguments

```
C:\> dir win*
 Volume in drive C is BSOD
 Volume Serial Number is 4AFF-AE03

 Directory of C:\

03/01/2011  07:58 AM    <DIR>          Windows
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               1 Dir(s)  393,128,820,736 bytes free
```

as expected, but doing

```
C:\> dir win*\sys*
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

and

```
C:\> dir windows\sys*
 Volume in drive C is BSOD
 Volume Serial Number is 4AFF-AE03

 Directory of C:\windows

13/07/2009  08:36 PM    <DIR>          system
10/06/2009  03:08 PM               219 system.ini
10/02/2011  07:55 AM    <DIR>          System32
09/02/2011  04:33 PM    <DIR>          SysWOW64
               1 File(s)            219 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  393,128,816,640 bytes free
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up just specifying each directory: `dir1\*.sql + dir2\*.sql ... copy.sql`. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do works on Unix (bash/sh), but unfortunately doesn't work on Windows CMD.

In Windows CMD do something like this:

```
del result.sql && FOR /F %G IN ('"dir *.sql /s /b"') DO type %G >> result.sql
```

It will delete `result.sql`, and for each file named *.sql in current and subdirectories (`dir *.sql /s /b`) append the content to result.sql (`type filename >> result.sql`).

There is also a FORFILES command, but unsure what version of Windows it was introduced in.

```
del result.sql && FORFILES /S /M *.sql /C "cmd /c type @path" > result.sql
```

(Note the && is just a way of adding multiple commands per line and can be replaced with standard newline (\r\n).)

Answer (score 0):

well I'm assuming all your sql files are text files so could you do something like

type *.sql >> copy.sql

Comment: hmm, forgot you wanted recursive but still...you could make use of a simple .bat  file...copy all the .sql files with copy's recursive parameter, into one directory, ">>" them into one file and then delete all the copied files

Comment: This would also work for one directory only. Like Marc said, you can't use a wildcard as part of the path. Thanks, though.

Comment: @J Benjamin - I guess our comments crossed in cyberspace. Thanks.